# Why does php artisan commands don't work after composer update

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm using **Laravel 5.4**, I ran composer update to update to the latest version which is **5.4.27**. When i tried to run my server with the command php artisan serve, it doesn't work and I keep getting this error on all the php artisan commands
     [ErrorException]
  file_put_contents(/bootstrap/cache/
  services.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: is it ubuntu os?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that artisan can't write to 'bootstrap/cache/services.php'
You can fix this issue by changing the permissions using chmod:

```
# chmod 664 bootstrap/cache/services.php
```

Also, don't forget to set the right owner/group of this file (probably www-data):

```
# chgrp www-data bootstrap/cache/services.php
```